# O(1) deletion for a JavaScript queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, hashmap, queue

How can I create a queue in JavaScript where I can add/remove elements in near O(1)/constant time? Right now I have a simple array as a queue, but to find an element to delete, I have to go through the array, and then call `Array.prototype.splice`.

Not only that but if you have a FIFO queue based on a simple array, you are going to need to call `Array.prototype.shift` or `Array.prototype.unshift`, and both those are O(N), because they have to update the indices of each item in the array.

So I am looking to get constant time insertion/deletion of elements anywhere in the list/queue. A plain array doesn't seem to yield that if you try to make it into a FIFO queue.

Comment: `pop()` or `shift()` are the inverse operators. You should only need splice for removing from the "middle" of an array. The others work on the ends

Comment: Yes but I need to remove from the middle of the array, that's the problem.

Comment: I only need to insert at the ends, but I need to delete from the middle.

Comment: You could use a `Set` instead, which has O(1) insertion/lookup/delete complexity in modern engines IIRC

Comment: Set is a good idea, but then how do I store order of the queue, in other words, how can I implement pop() /push()/shift()/unshift() on Set.

Comment: `Set.prototype.values()` iterates over the set's values in insertion order, might be enough for what you want

Comment: Insertion order isn't good enough in my case because sometimes I add to the front of the queue and sometimes to the back.

Comment: A linked list is the only thing I can think of, but that sounds hairy

Comment: I made some updates to the question/answer, to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I've thought about this for awhile and all I can come up with is a doubly linked list. A doubly linked list allows us to add/remove items from the queue in constant time.

See answer here:

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-create-a-queue-in-JavaScript-where-I-can-search-for-or-remove-elements-in-near-O-1-time-Right-now-I-have-a-simple-array-as-a-queue-but-to-find-an-element-to-delete-I-have-to-go-through-the-array-and-then

Here is an implementation that seems to work:

https://github.com/ORESoftware/linked-queue

A simple example of why this works is, with an array, each shift/unshift call is O(N), so the following takes 80 seconds!

```
const values = [];

const t = Date.now();

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  values.unshift({});
}

console.log('total time:', Date.now() - t); // 80 seconds!
```

However if we add to the front of a queue, with the above library, it takes just 60ms. More than 2 orders of magnitude difference. Huge.

```
const {LinkedQueue} = require('@oresoftware/linked-queue');

const q = new LinkedQueue();

const t = Date.now();

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  q.addToFront({});
}

console.log('total time:', Date.now() - t);  // 60 milliseconds!
```